# Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

When I run an insert query:

```
"INSERT INTO filelist (username, filename, fileloc, filephoto, loanId) VALUES
  ('".$client."','".$filename."','".$filepdf."','".$file."','".$loanId."')");
```

I get an error that says:

```
Unknown column 'filephoto' in 'field list'
```

But that is incorrect because here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `filelist` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`filename` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`fileloc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`filephoto` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`loanId` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I tried putting filephoto in quotes and backticks but no success.

Any ideas on what would fix this?

Comment: You've tried putting backticks around all the field names?

Comment: Don't create your queries with concatenation. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Does it work from the MySQL client?

Comment: Perhaps you could echo sql query out and show us the actual text.

Comment: Make sure that you connected to a proper database or that a database you connecting to actually contains the same table schema as you showed. Now, you have a missing comma in your `CREATE TABLE` statement right before `PRIMARY KEY`. Other than that MySQL shouldn't complain about unknown column. Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc385/1) demo.

Comment: I have tried using backticks around all and I know I'm connecting properly.  I also ran into this using a prepared statement.

Comment: @Joe If you want help then post the result of concatenation variables' values into the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the engine to MyISAM fixed this issue.

I had recreated the table multiple times with no luck but changing to MyISAM fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

you have a redundant ) on the end of your query. I guess this will be a copy paste mistake :-)

however I would try this query

```
'INSERT INTO filelist (username, filename, fileloc, filephoto, loanId) VALUES ("'.$client.'", "'.$filename.'", "'.$filepdf.'", "'.$file.'", "'.$loanId.'" )';
```

I had previous troubles with ' and " in queries.

Comment: Thanks, it was a copy paste mistake but even with the different quotes I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I created a table using the SQL you provided above and then running the following query seems to work fine form me.

```
"INSERT INTO filelist (username, filename, fileloc, filephoto, loanId) VALUES
  ('$client','$filename','$filepdf','$file','$loanId')"
```